# Download attachments from Outlook while system/computer is off

Tags: vba, outlook

I have VBA code that downloads attachments from my email.

For the script to run successfully I have to keep my system/computer switched on.

I want to download these files on a server and do not want to keep my computer switched on all the time. Is there a utility/software that allows me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Exchange can only run server side rules on the server. Running a script in general or saving an attachment in particular is not something Exchange will do.